# Why is the following code giving Segmentation fault in codechef, but is working absolutely right elsewhere

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, segmentation-fault

The following code runs pretty good in codeblocks and several online compilers, but it gives segmentation fault whenever submitted.

As per my knowledge, seg fault occurs whenever we try to access some memory which is not allocated, but how and where is that taking place ??

```
#include<stdio.h>
int minimum(int a[][300],int n)
{
    int flag=0,minval=100000000,mini,i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(a[j][i]!=0&&flag==0)
            {
                temp=a[j][i];
                flag=1;
            }
            else if(a[j][i]!=0&&temp!=a[j][i])
            {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==1&&temp<minval)
        {
            minval=temp;
            mini=i;
            flag=0;
        }
    } 
    return mini;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,t,n,a[300][300],copy[300],column,subt;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(j!=i)
                    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
                else
                    a[i][j]=0;
            }
        column=minimum(a,n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            if(a[i][column]==0)
                break;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            copy[j]=a[i][j];
        subt=a[(i+1)%n][column];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(copy[i]==0)
                copy[i]+=subt;
            else
                copy[i]+=1;
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%d ",copy[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to submit the exact same code in python(exact same logic). That's similarly running pretty everywhere, but gives NZEC whenever submitted.

```
def minimum(a,n):
    flag=0
    minval=max(max(a))+1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if a[j][i]!=0 and flag==0:
                temp=a[j][i]
                flag=1
            elif a[j][i]!=0 and temp!=a[j][i]:
                flag=0
                break
        if flag==1 and temp<minval:
            minval=temp
            mini=i
            flag=0
    return mini

for i in range(input()):
    n=input()
    a=[]
    copy=[]
    for j in range(n):
        temp=(map(int,raw_input().split()))
        temp.insert(j,0)
        copy=temp[:]
        a.append(copy)
        del temp

    column=minimum(a,n)
    print column
    for k in range(n):
        if a[k][column]==0:
            break
    copy=a[k][:]    
    subt=a[(k+1)%n][column]
    for k in range(n):
        if copy[k]==0:
            copy[k]=copy[k]+subt
        else:
            copy[k]=copy[k]+1

    del a
    for item in copy:
        print item,
    print
```

How can the same code generate two types of run-time errors in two programming languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `minimum` could possibly return an uninitialized value, if `mini` was never set during your scan of the array.  I'm not sure what your logic is supposed to be, but perhaps you should initialize `mini = 0` at the top of your function or do something else to prevent this from happening.  You didn't specify what was supposed to be in the given matrix, but as an example a matrix of all zeroes would trigger this behavior.